# Why is the editor showing up in custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types

I am creating a custom content type and on the add new page and edit page the *editor* is currently showing up when I have it coded not to be there. This was working fine about a week ago and I'm unsure what went wrong. Any ideas?

Here is the code from my functions page:

```
add_action('init', 'recipe_register');

function recipe_register() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('Recipes', 'post type general recipe'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Person', 'post type singular name'),
        'add_new' => _x('Add New Recipe', 'recipe'),
        'add_new_recipe' => __('Add New Recipe'),
        'edit_recipe' => __('Edit Recipe'),
        'new_recipe' => __('New Recipe'),
        'view_recipe' => __('View Recipe'),
        'search_recipes' => __('Search Recipes'),
        'not_found' =>  __('Nothing found'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash'),
        'parent_item_colon' => ''
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array("slug" => "recipes"),
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'menu_position' => null,
        'supports' => array('title','author','thumbnail')
      ); 


    register_post_type('recipe',$args);

    register_taxonomy('type','recipe',array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'label' => 'Type',
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'type' ),
    ));
}



add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'recipe',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Recipe' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Recipe' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'recipe')
        )
    );
}


add_action("admin_init", "admin_init");

function admin_init(){
    add_meta_box("recipedetails_meta", "Recipe Information", "recipe_meta",  "recipe", "normal", "low");
}

function recipe_meta() {
  global $post;
  $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
  $name = $custom["recipe_name"][0];
  $yield = $custom["recipe_yield"][0];
  $time = $custom["recipe_time"][0];
  $ingredients = $custom["recipe_ingredients"][0];
  $directions = $custom["recipe_directions"][0];
  $calories = $custom["recipe_calories"][0];
  $done = $custom["recipe_done"][0];
  $original = $custom["recipe_original"][0];
  ?>  

    <div id='peoplemanager_form_container'>

        <div id='shortanswers'>
            <p><label>Name</label><br /><input name="recipe_name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>"></p>
            <p><label>Yield</label><br /><input name="recipe_yield" value="<?php echo $yield; ?>"></p>
            <p><label>Time</label><br /><input name="recipe_time" value="<?php echo $time; ?>"></p>
            <p><label>Calories</label><br /><input name="recipe_calories" value="<?php echo $calories; ?>"></p>
            <p><label>URL</label><br /><input name="recipe_fat" value="<?php echo $done; ?>"></p>
            <p><label>Original</label><br /><input name="recipe_original" value="<?php echo $original; ?>"></p>
            <p><label>Ingredients:</label><br />
            <textarea cols="50" rows="5" name="recipe_ingredients"><?php echo $ingredients; ?></textarea></p>
            <p><label>Directions:</label><br />
            <textarea cols="50" rows="5" name="recipe_directions"><?php echo $directions; ?></textarea></p>

        </div>
    </div>
  <?php
}

add_action('save_post', 'save_details');

function save_details(){
  global $post;

  update_post_meta($post->ID, "recipe_name", $_POST["recipe_name"]);
  update_post_meta($post->ID, "recipe_yield", $_POST["recipe_yield"]);
  update_post_meta($post->ID, "recipe_time", $_POST["recipe_time"]);
  update_post_meta($post->ID, "recipe_ingredients", $_POST["recipe_ingredients"]);
  update_post_meta($post->ID, "recipe_directions", $_POST["recipe_directions"]);
  update_post_meta($post->ID, "recipe_calories", $_POST["recipe_calories"]);
  update_post_meta($post->ID, "recipe_done", $_POST["recipe_done"]);
}



add_filter('manage_edit-recipe_columns', 'add_recipe_columns');

function add_recipe_columns($gallery_columns) {
    $new_columns['cb'] = '<input type="checkbox" />';
    $new_columns['title'] = _x('Recipe', 'column name');
    $new_columns['calories'] = __('Calories');
    $new_columns['time'] = __('Time');
    $new_columns['type'] = __('Type');
    return $new_columns;
}


add_action('manage_recipe_posts_custom_column', 'manage_recipe_columns', 10, 2);

function manage_recipe_columns($column_name, $id) {
    global $post;
    switch ($column_name) {
        case 'calories':
            echo get_post_meta( $post->ID , 'recipe_calories' , true ); 
            break;
        case 'time': 
            echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'recipe_time' , true );
            break;
        case 'type':
            echo get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'type', '', ', ','');
            break;

        default:
            break;
    } 
}

?>
```

Comment: Its showing on add/edit new page or add edit of you custom post type? Also you can use `remove_post_type_support( $post_type, $feature )` to remove the editor from any post type.

Answer (score 1):

you are getting the the editor because of the function ***create_post_type()*** in your code that you have shown above, it is duplicating the function ***recipe_register()***. Just remove the *create_post_type* and every thing should be fine.